# Rails 4 Redirects to True Host URL instead of Current Host URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Our Rails application lives on a website, `app.example.com` and sits behind a AWS Cloudfront system using a Lamdba method that determines which traffic to pass through from `cf.example.com` to `app.example.com` or `app2.example.com`. So if I navigate to `cf.example.com/my_page` it displays content from `app.example.com/my_page` without editing the hostname.

On any Rails redirects (redirect_to or router method redirect) it is changing my url from `cf.example.com` to `app.example.com`.

Example:

```
/routes.rb
root to: redirect('/log_in')
```

On `cf.example.com`, Rails returns 302 where location is `app.example.com/log_in`

I need to keep this url as `cf.example.com/log_in`. How can I stop Rails 4 from changing my location to its hosted location?

I am using Passenger with Ruby on Rails 4.